# NetBIOS ping issues

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, netbios

I am having an issue with NetBIOS Pinging. When I ping a PC/Server on the network with its NetBIOS Name I am finding that the PC/Server is getting associated with an IP address outside my network (IP 92.242.140.21 to be specific) and this will continue to do so until I do ipconfig /renew on the pinging machine. I am at a loss as to why this is happening. I'm thinking this is a DNS issue but when I look at the DNS records the machines all show the correct FDQN associated with a network IP assigned to the machine. Please provide some avenues for me to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: What's the actual issue?  I have a hard time believing that the real problem is that you can't ping by NETBIOS name.

Comment: I can ping by netbios name but its intermittent.  Every so often it breaks from the internal ip address associated with the FDQN name. i.e.      ping NetwkPC -> get NetwkPC.mydomain.com [192.168.xxx.xxx]                       ping NetwkPC again -> get NetwkPC.mydomain.com [92.242.140.21].  This IP is out in the internet somewhere.  This is my issue

Comment: OK, and presumably, the problem isn't that pings go to the wrong IP address, but that everything does... whatever you're actually trying to use, right?  Check your DNS and WINS servers for this `92.242.140.21` address, as well as the hosts file on the machine you're pinging with.  That address is coming from somewhere, may as well check the obvious places first.

Comment: Been there done that!!  That's what makes this so frigging perplexing. This is a network-wide issue. It's happening on all machines.  I'm really trying to figure out how its getting associated with that outside IP address really.  If the DNS server has NetwkPC associated with the FDQN NetwkPC.mydomain.com [192.168.xxx.xxx] internally, how the heck is it getting associated with [92.242.140.21]?  FYI, all machine FDQN's will get associated with that same bogus outside IP Address.

Comment: Well, it's typically a wildcard entry, but the intermittent nature of it makes it hard to pin down.  Can you isolate it to devices on one switch or AP or connecting to a particular DC or server?

Comment: Because it is happening on ALL machines, I'm ruling out switches. I do have one machine connecting via VPN that keeps forcing MB elections but I'm not sure if that would be a cause nor am I certian of how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: When this VPN machine is NOT connected, do you still have the issue?

Comment: Master Browser elections don't relate to name resolution AFAIK. The behavior you're seeing when pinging an unqualified name 
(assuming that these machines are AD domain joined and have a computer primary DNS suffix) is normal and expected. The results aren't. Again, assuming an AD domain, are all of the clients using only the AD DNS server for DNS? Is the AD DNS server itself only using itself for DNS (assuming you've only got 1 server)?

Comment: Also, what's the DNS suffix of your AD domain (again assuming an AD domain)?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue.  It seems there were multiple routers set up in DHCP and the computers were loading them all so it was creating routing issues.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @UpTooL8 I believe 92.242.140.21 is the Verizon  SearchAssist service. You'll get the same resolution when pinging ad.google.com.  Verizon is great, but this address resolution isn't, and I feel it's in violation of naming standards.